# Working Postfix with NO CHANGES kept receiving mail but when sending got 'mail for <domain> loops back to myself'

Tags: networking, email, postfix

I had this classic error message for which I found DOZENS of pre-existing asked-and-answered questions scattered here and throughout the internet. **However, they were not my situation.**

In every one of those I read, **they were all about getting a new configuration working and that's what sets this apart.** In my case, everything was humming right along, I was getting the usual daily spam and thought everything was OK, but then an email list (mailman) which I administer on the same box suddenly had an entire list get "bounce failure removals," and I got the notifications of that.

That alerted me to the problem, I looked at the logs, found the above error, and was deeply puzzled; **no cracker (black-hat hacker) would *disable sending email*,** I wouldn't think, and I didn't alter the configuration, so, **what do we have here, bit-rot?** I tried pinging the domains listed - they pinged. Hmmm...

The network topology includes two dedicated gateways (NOT appliances but actual linux installations), a couple of web servers, and some internal servers. The mail server is on an internal network and gets fed inbound email from a port forward through either of the two gateways (multiple MX records) - pretty standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**It often helps to consider all the things going on in an environment.** In this case, it's an older server-farm (23 years and counting), and new hardware gets brought in now and then as old hardware ages out, and this problem occurred while **three new servers were being configured and being prepared to put into service.**

One of the gateways had failed from age and the other was long-in-the-tooth as well. One of the web servers had been pressed into service as an additional gateway to help give redundancy while provisioning new hardware. To balance the load a bit, **inbound email was using the surviving gateway for port-forwarding and the web server was given default-route duties for the internal net to the outside world.**

**It was under these conditions that the surviving gateway decided to have a very strange failure;** it was receiving from the internet and forwarding packets but it wasn't letting the mail server respond in the same path backwards to the net, probably redirecting it to forward back to the mail server itself, and thus the failure. At least, this is my conjecture; I never bothered to diagnose the gateway as it was about to be replaced anyway. ...I'm pretty sure ping from the mail server worked because it was using the web-server gateway for that use, or it was because it was also using the gateway for the default route and that aspect of the gateway was still working.

As it happened, one of the two web servers had also aged out and so **a new web server had been brought up and put online, and it was promptly configured to do the port-forwarding and NAT to also do gateway duty, the mail server had its primary route set to the new box, the DNS was pointed at the web server, and instantly it all started working again with no changes whatsoever to the mail server except pointing its default route to the new box.**